# How to bind through an array in a column?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where I am binding cubicleList array elements to the columns.But my problem is for binding details of commercial reference, I am using ng-init=getCR(obj,index).

This passes one by one value of array of cubiclelist to this function. Because of the ng-repeat loop my getCR() function is getting called as many times as there are number of elements in cubicleList.

I want to call my getCR() function only once as internally I am calling a service. I do not want to call this function as many times as the no of elements in loop and bind my commercial reference column through this loop. How can I do it?

Below is my code

```
<table id="viewBom_tbl_cubicle1" class="table table-bordered form">
                                                    <tbody ng-init="total = 0">
                                                        <tr style="background: grey;color:white;">
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">SL NO</th>
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Cubicle Name</th>
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Commercial Reference</th>
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Unit Purchasing Price ({{selectedCurrency}})</th>
                                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Sub Total ({{selectedCurrency}})</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr ng-hide="cubicleList.length">
                                                            <td colspan="9" style="text-align:center;">No Records!</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr ng-click="showViewBOM(obj);" ng-model="rowSel" class="rtc_row" ng-repeat="obj in cubicleList track by $index" ng-init="getDetails()" >
                                                            <td style="text-align:center;">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align:left;">{{obj.cubicleArray[0].CubicleFunction}} - {{obj.cubicleArray[0].ActiveTab}} - {{obj.cubicleArray[0].ActiveTabOptions}}</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align:center;" ng-init="getCR(obj,index)">{{obj.cubicleArray[0].CommercialReference}}</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align:center;" ng-value="obj.cubicleArray[0].Quantity = TechnicalCharacteristicsObject.SwitchBoardQuantity">{{obj.cubicleArray[0].Quantity}}</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align:center;" ng-init="getUnitPurchasePrice(obj,$index)">{{obj.cubicleArray[0].perUnitPrice | number : 2}}</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align:center;" ng-value="obj.cubicleArray[0].TotalCost = obj.cubicleArray[0].Quantity * obj.cubicleArray[0].perUnitPrice ">{{obj.cubicleArray[0].TotalCost | number : 2}}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
```

Comment: show controller code also

Comment: Try to execute your getCR method once in the controller, and then store the result in a var, which will be displayed in your table